# Find the visible UITableViewCell when user scrolls to it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using the following code to find the visible cells in my tableview. Everytime the user scrolls only one UITableViewCell is visible to the user but the code below returns two visible rows because this is how the UITableView functioning when user scrolls to a cell.

```
 NSArray *visibleCells  = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
    for (NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath in visibleCells)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellIndexPath];
     if ([cell isKindOfClass:[C8SubmittedContentTableViewCell class]]) {
         [submittedContentTableViewCell play];
        }
    }
```

I run the code above at

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
```

But as i mentioned UITableView returns two visible cells. How would i know which one of them is really visible to the user? Because if i have two or three videos in a row i need to start playing only the one that is really visible to the user and at the same time stop playing the previous one.

Any thoughts or help appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a "paginated" scrolling? Otherwise it's not quite clear how only one cell can be visible, because you anyway get portion of more than one cell visible while scrolling between them

Comment: Yes i use for pagination this code in scrollViewWillEndDragging
    self.tableView.rowHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat rowHeight = self.tableView.rowHeight;
    int tomove = ((int)targetContentOffset->y % (int)self.tableView.rowHeight);
    if(tomove < self.tableView.rowHeight/6 || velocity.y < 0){
            targetContentOffset->y -= tomove;
        else{
            targetContentOffset->y += (self.tableView.rowHeight-tomove);
        }}

Comment: I think better you add screenshots of 1 cell visible.... also give border to the tableview and check tableview CGRect first

Comment: @FahimParkar can not share screen because is a project of a friend. Used NSLog to print the vaues of CGRect cellRect and CGRect visibleRect for the two first cells. I get: cellcgrect: {{0, 0}, {375, 545}} - visiblecellrect: {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}
cellcgrect: {{0, 545}, {375, 545}} - visiblecellrect: {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}
cellcgrect: {{0, 0}, {375, 545}} - visiblecellrect: {{0, 103}, {375, 667}}
cellcgrect: {{0, 545}, {375, 545}} - visiblecellrect: {{0, 103}, {375, 667}} based on the answer of Asperi below.

Comment: Even better results. App loads and shows first cell. The results are: cellcgrect: {{0, 0}, {375, 545}} - visiblecellrect: {{0, 0}, {375, 667}} - isCellVisible: 1 - cellIndexPath.row: 0
cellcgrect: {{0, 545}, {375, 545}} - visiblecellrect: {{0, 0}, {375, 667}} - isCellVisible: 0 - cellIndexPath.row: 1 Now user scrolls to second cell. The results are cellcgrect: {{0, 0}, {375, 545}} - visiblecellrect: {{0, 134}, {375, 667}} - isCellVisible: 0 - cellIndexPath.row: 0
cellcgrect: {{0, 545}, {375, 545}} - visiblecellrect: {{0, 134}, {375, 667}} - isCellVisible: 0 - cellIndexPath.row: 1 ... ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible way:

```
CGRect cellRect = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:cellIndexPath];

CGRect visibleRect;
visibleRect.origin = self.tableView.contentOffset;
visibleRect.size = self.tableView.bounds.size;

BOOL isCellVisible = CGRectContainsRect(visibleRect, cellRect);
```

Your layout is not clear so possible `CGRectIntersectsRect` might be needed, or even manual rect to rect matching (say, if cell rect is always bigger then table clip area, the percentage of overlapping should be used).

Comment: Thanks sir!Is this the way it should be used cause worked only for first cell! NSArray *vsbCells  = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]; for (NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath in vsbCells) {UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellIndexPath];if ([cell isKindOfClass:[TableViewCell class]]) {CGRect cellRect = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:cellIndexPath]; CGRect vsbRect; visibleRect.origin = self.tableView.contentOffset; vsbRect.size = self.tableView.bounds.size; BOOL isCellVisible = CGRectContainsRect(vsbRect, cellRect);if(isCellVisible){[TableViewCell play];}
}}

Comment: Actually i tried both CGRectIntersectsRect and CGRectContainsRect. CGRectContainsRect returns 1 for first time and then always 0 for other cells. CGRectIntersectsRect on the other hand returns always 1...

Comment: Used NSLog to print the vaues of CGRect cellRect and CGRect visibleRect for the two first cells. I get: cellcgrect: {{0, 0}, {375, 545}} - visiblecellrect: {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}
cellcgrect: {{0, 545}, {375, 545}} - visiblecellrect: {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}
cellcgrect: {{0, 0}, {375, 545}} - visiblecellrect: {{0, 103}, {375, 667}}
cellcgrect: {{0, 545}, {375, 545}} - visiblecellrect: {{0, 103}, {375, 667}} based on your answer.

Comment: Even better results. App loads and shows first cell. The results are: cellcgrect: {{0, 0}, {375, 545}} - visiblecellrect: {{0, 0}, {375, 667}} - isCellVisible: 1 - cellIndexPath.row: 0
cellcgrect: {{0, 545}, {375, 545}} - visiblecellrect: {{0, 0}, {375, 667}} - isCellVisible: 0 - cellIndexPath.row: 1 Now user scrolls to second cell. The results are cellcgrect: {{0, 0}, {375, 545}} - visiblecellrect: {{0, 134}, {375, 667}} - isCellVisible: 0 - cellIndexPath.row: 0
cellcgrect: {{0, 545}, {375, 545}} - visiblecellrect: {{0, 134}, {375, 667}} - isCellVisible: 0 - cellIndexPath.row: 1 ... ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use delegate's `willDisplayCell` for starting video playing and `didEndDisplayingCell` for stopping.